# CURLOPT_VERBOSE isn't sending to STDERR

Tags: curl

Ubuntu 20.04 using libcurl and the following code, I can view the output from the command line.
HOWEVER, when redirecting output `./run_me 2>&1 > output.log` the cURL output still displays on the screen and does NOT get redirected to the `output.log` file.

The cURL documentation states that the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` without setting `CURLOPT_STDERR` should go to `STDERR`.  However, it appears it does not.

How do we redirect the cURL output to `STDERR`?

```
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
char errBuff[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
if(curl) {
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    chunk.size = 0;
    chunk.memory = calloc(1,sizeof(*chunk.memory));
    if ( !chunk.memory ) {
      return CURLE_FAILED_INIT;
    }

    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, username);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, password);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, trustStore);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, clientCert);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, clientKey);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, clientKeyPass);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errBuff );
    errBuff[0] = 0; // empty the error buffer   
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

    struct curl_slist* list = NULL;
    list = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type: application/json");
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Accept: application/json");
    char clBuf[30];
    (void)snprintf(clBuf, 30, "Content-Length: %d", (int)strlen(postData));
    list = curl_slist_append(list, clBuf);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    (void)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postData);
    long httpCode = 0;
    int res = CURLE_FAILED_INIT;
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    (void)curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, &httpCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer has to do with how the shell treats the ordering of the redirections.

From the bash manual:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the
> command
>
> ```
>   ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs both standard output and standard error to the file dirlist,
> while the command
>
> ```
>   ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard
> error was duplicated from the standard output before the standard
> output was redirected to dirlist.

Changing the command to `./run_me > output.log 2>&1` should result in curl's verbose output also being redirected to the file.

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot about that caveat of Linux.